# htaccess Rewrite - adds .PHP and breaks LessCSS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Hello Stackers,**

I'm having a problem with my .htaccess file. I'm rewriting the URL `example.com/register.php?key=VALUE` to `example.com/registratie/VALUE`Hower, this will Break my `general.less` include, and add a PHP to the end of the variable. For Example, `VALUE` will be `VALUE.php`. Am I Doing something wrong?

**My LESS Include in the header.php File**

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="includes/style/general.less" />
```

**My .HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^registratie/([^/]+)(|/)$ register.php?key=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule matches everything that is not a file or dir .  reorder your rules like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^registratie/([^/]+)/?$ register.php?key=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This did indeed fix my problem.